# how do i convert xml attributes to c++ class using tinyxml

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing, glfw

Hey i am trying to create a firework display by reading in the fireworks off a .xml file, which will then iterate through and launch each firework.

I followed a tutorial on dinomage to find out how to use tinyxml, i learnt that i can store the attributes into char pointers but i dont know how to convert them to GLfloats to store them in my class variables.

I did try using atof but when i ran the program i got loads of errors which im guessing is because the pointer only stores the address which im passing to my variable.

can anybody point out where im going wrong and how i can go about fixing the issue?

**Update**

i have found out that tinyxml is not compatible with vs2010 but tinyxml 2 is, so i have changed my code but am still having trouble loading my attributes i have added error checking, and it prints out that the xml has loaded but then it wont load the root

code updated

code: Firework.h

```
#ifndef FIREWORK_H
#define FIREWORK_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <string>



const GLint particles= 50;

 class Firework

 {

 public:

            GLint x[particles];
            GLint y[particles];
            GLint VelX[particles];
            GLint VelY[particles];
            GLint Xpos;
            GLint Ypos;
            GLint Xspeed;
            GLint Yspeed;



            unsigned char red;
            unsigned char blue;
            unsigned char green;
            GLfloat alpha;
            GLfloat redStart;
            GLfloat blueStart;
            GLfloat greenStart;
            std::string hexColour;
            std::string type;

            GLint timeUntilLaunch;
            GLint startTime;
            GLint endTime;
            GLint duration;
            GLfloat particleSize;
            GLboolean hasExploded;




            GLboolean rocket, fountain;

            static const GLfloat gravity;
            static const GLfloat baseYSpeed;
            static const GLfloat maxYSpeed;

            Firework();

            void initialise();
            void move();
            void explode();




 };




#endif
```

Firework.ccp

```
#include "Firework.h"
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include<time.h>
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const GLfloat Firework::gravity = 0.05f;
const GLfloat Firework::baseYSpeed = -4.0f;
const GLfloat Firework::maxYSpeed = -4.0f;

//int QueryAttributeStatus = elem->FirstChildElement("begin")- >QueryFloatAttribute(attr,&timeUntillLaunch);





int convertFromHex(string hex)

{

    int value = 0;



    int a = 0;

    int b = hex.length() - 1;

    for (; b >= 0; a++, b--)

    {

        if (hex[b] >= '0' && hex[b] <= '9')

        {

            value += (hex[b] - '0') * (1 << (a * 4));

        }

        else

        {

            switch (hex[b])

            {

                case 'A':

                case 'a':

                    value += 10 * (1 << (a * 4));

                    break;



                case 'B':

                case 'b':

                    value += 11 * (1 << (a * 4));

                    break;



                case 'C':

                case 'c':

                    value += 12 * (1 << (a * 4));

                    break;



                case 'D':

                case 'd':

                    value += 13 * (1 << (a * 4));

                    break;



                case 'E':

                case 'e':

                    value += 14 * (1 << (a * 4));

                    break;



                case 'F':

                case 'f':

                    value += 15 * (1 << (a * 4));

                    break;



                default:

                    cout << "Error, invalid charactare '" << hex[a] << "' in hex number" << endl;

                    break;

            }

        }

    }
        return value;

}


void hextodec(string hex, vector<unsigned char>& rgb)

{

/*  
    since there is no prefix attached to hex, use this code

    string redString = hex.substr(0, 2);

    string greenString = hex.substr(2, 2);

    string blueString = hex.substr(4, 2);
*/



/*

    if the prefix # was attached to hex, use the following code

    string redString = hex.substr(1, 2);

    string greenString = hex.substr(3, 2);

    string blueString = hex.substr(5, 2);

*/





    //if the prefix 0x was attached to hex, use the following code

    string redString = hex.substr(2, 2);

    string greenString = hex.substr(4, 2);

    string blueString = hex.substr(6, 2);





    unsigned char red = (unsigned char)(convertFromHex(redString));

    unsigned char green = (unsigned char)(convertFromHex(greenString));

    unsigned char blue = (unsigned char)(convertFromHex(blueString));



    rgb[0] = red;

    rgb[1] = green;

    rgb[2] = blue;

}


Firework::Firework()
{

    initialise();

}



void Firework::initialise()
{
    tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile( "fireworks.xml");
    if (!doc.LoadFile("fireworks.xml"))
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to load file: no xml"<<endl;
    }

    else
        std::cout<<"loaded xml"<<endl;



        tinyxml2::XMLElement * root = doc.FirstChildElement();
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            std::cout<<"Failed to load file: no root element."<<endl;

        }

        else

            std::cout<<"root node loaded"<<endl;

        for (tinyxml2::XMLElement* elem = root ->FirstChildElement(); elem!=NULL; elem = elem->NextSiblingElement())
        {
            string elemName = elem->Value();
            const char* attr;

            if (elemName == "Firework")
            {
                attr = elem->Attribute("begin");
                if(attr != NULL)
                {
                    elem->QueryIntAttribute("begin",&startTime);
                }

                attr = elem->Attribute("type");
                if (attr != NULL)
                {
                    type = elem->GetText();
                    if (type != "")

                        std::cout<<"have something"<<endl; 


                }

                attr = elem ->Attribute("colour");
                if (attr !=NULL)
                {
                    hexColour= elem->GetText();
                     vector<unsigned char> rgbColor(3);

                     hextodec(hexColour,rgbColor);

                     red =int(rgbColor[0]);
                     blue = int(rgbColor[1]);
                     green= int(rgbColor[2]);


                }

                attr = elem->Attribute("duration");
                if (attr !=NULL)
                {
                    elem->QueryIntAttribute("duration", &endTime);
                }

                for (tinyxml2::XMLElement * e =elem ->FirstChildElement("Position"); e != NULL; e = e->NextSiblingElement("Position"))
                {
                    attr = e->Attribute("x");
                    if (attr != NULL)
                    {
                        Xpos = e->QueryIntAttribute("x", &Xpos);
                    }

                    attr = e->Attribute("y");
                    if (attr != NULL)
                    {
                        Ypos = e->QueryIntAttribute("y", &Ypos);
                    }
                }

                for(tinyxml2::XMLElement * v =elem ->FirstChildElement("Velocity"); v !=NULL; v = v->NextSiblingElement("Velocity"))
                {
                    attr = v -> Attribute("x");
                        if (attr != NULL)
                    {
                        Xspeed = v ->QueryIntAttribute("x", &Xspeed);
                    }

                    attr = v ->Attribute ("y");
                        if (attr !=NULL)
                    {
                        Yspeed = v ->QueryIntAttribute("y", &Yspeed);
                    }
                }
            }

        }









    //Setting initial x/y locations and speeds for each particle
    for (int loop = 0; loop < particles; loop++)
    {
        x[loop] = Xpos;
        y[loop] = Ypos;
        VelX[loop] = Xspeed;
        VelY[loop] = Yspeed;
    }

    //intiallising the colour and full alpha
    redStart   = 0.85f;//((float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
    greenStart = 0.55f;//((float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
    blueStart  = 0.01f;//((float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);

    alpha = 1.0f;

    timeUntilLaunch = startTime;
    duration = endTime;
    particleSize = 1.0f + ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)* 3.0f;

    hasExploded = false;
}

void Firework::move()
{
    for (int loop = 0; loop < particles; loop++)
    {
        if (timeUntilLaunch <= 0)
        {   
            x[loop] += VelX [loop];
            y[loop] += VelY [loop];
            VelY[loop] += Firework::gravity;
            duration --;
        }

    }
    timeUntilLaunch --;

    if (duration <= 0)
    {
        for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < particles; loop2++)
        {
            VelX[loop2] = -4 + (rand() / (int)RAND_MAX)*8;
            VelY[loop2] = -4 + (rand() / (int)RAND_MAX)*8;
        }
         hasExploded = true;
    }
}


void Firework::explode()
{
       for (int loop = 0; loop < particles; loop++)
    {
        // Dampen the horizontal speed by 1% per frame
       VelX[loop] *= 0.99f;

        // Move the particle
        x[loop] += VelX[loop];
        y[loop] += VelY[loop];

        // Apply gravity to the particle's speed
        VelY[loop] += Firework::gravity;
    }

    // Fade out the particles (alpha is stored per firework, not per particle)
    if (alpha > 0.0f)
    {
        alpha -= 0.01f;
    }
    else // Once the alpha hits zero, then reset the firework
    {
        initialise();
    }
}
```

Main.ccp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h> // *** IMPORTANT: Uncomment for Win32 systems - This must come -BEFORE- gl.h in the include list! ***
#include "GL\glfw.h"
#include "Firework.h"
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include "tinyxml2.h"


#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "lib/glfw/GLFW.lib")

 using namespace std;


 GLint windowWidth = 1024;
 GLint windowHeight = 600;
 GLint frameCount =0;
 GLint texture;

 const int FIREWORKS = 15; // Number of fireworks

 Firework fw[FIREWORKS];


 void initGL()

 {
     glfwSwapInterval(1);


     glfwSetWindowTitle("Fireworks");

     glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)windowWidth, (GLsizei)windowHeight);

     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

     glLoadIdentity();

     glOrtho(0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, 0, 1);

     glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    // Set our clear colour to opaque black
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Disable depth testing (because we're working in 2D!)
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Enable blending (we need this to be able to use an alpha component)
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Set the accumulation buffer clearing colour to opaque black
    glClearAccum(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);

}

 void drawScene()

 {
     // Take the contents of the current accumulation buffer and copy it to the colour buffer so that it entirely overwrites it
    glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.0f);

    // Clear the accumulation buffer (don't worry, we re-grab the screen into the accumulation buffer after drawing our current frame!)
    glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set ModelView matrix mode and reset to the default identity matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Displacement trick for exact pixelisation
    glTranslatef(0.375, 0.375, 0);

    // Draw our fireworks
    for (int loop = 0; loop < FIREWORKS; loop++)
    {
        for (int particleLoop = 0; particleLoop < particles; particleLoop++)
        {

            // Set the point size of the firework particles (this needs to be called BEFORE opening the glBegin(GL_POINTS) section!)
            glPointSize(fw[loop].particleSize);

            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                // Set colour to yellow on the way up, then whatever colour firework should be when exploded   

            if (fw[loop].hasExploded == false)
                {
                    glColor4f(fw[loop].redStart, fw[loop].greenStart, fw[loop].blueStart, 1.0f);
                }
                else
                {
                    glColor4f(fw[loop].red, fw[loop].green, fw[loop].blue, fw[loop].alpha);
                }

                // Draw the point
                glVertex2f(fw[loop].x[particleLoop], fw[loop].y[particleLoop]);
            glEnd();
        }

        // Move the firework appropriately depending on its explosion state
        if (fw[loop].hasExploded == false && fw[loop].type=="Rocket")
        {
            fw[loop].move();
        }
        else
        {
            fw[loop].explode();
        }

 }

     glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 0.85f);

    glfwSwapBuffers();

 }


int main()
{
    int srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); // Seed the random number generator

    // Define our buffer settings
    int redBits     = 8,   greenBits = 8,    blueBits    = 8;
    int alphaBits  = 64, depthBits = 24,   stencilBits = 8;

    // Flag to keep our main loop running
    bool running = true;

    // Initialise glfw
    glfwInit();

    // Create a window
    if(!glfwOpenWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, redBits, greenBits, blueBits, alphaBits, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    {
        cout << "Failed to open window!" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
    }

    // Call our initGL function to set up our OpenGL options
    initGL();

    while (running == true)
    {
    // Draw our scene
    drawScene();

    // Increase our frame counter
    frameCount++;

    // Exit if ESC was pressed or the window was closed
    running = glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

firework.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<FireworkDisplay>
  <Firework begin="1000" type="Fountain" colour="0x20FF40" duration="5000">
    <Position x="0" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="2000" type="Fountain" colour="0x4020FF" duration="4000">
    <Position x="100" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="3000" type="Fountain" colour="0xff5099" duration="3000">
    <Position x="-100" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>

  <Firework begin="1000" type="Rocket" colour="0xFF2020" duration="1000">
    <Position x="500" y="-384"/>
    <Velocity x="-3" y="10"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="2000" type="Rocket" colour="0xFF2020" duration="1000">
    <Position x="0" y="-384"/>
    <Velocity x="0" y="10"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="3000" type="Rocket" colour="0xFF2020" duration="1000">
    <Position x="-500" y="-384"/>
    <Velocity x="3" y="10"/>
  </Firework>

  <Firework begin="11000" type="Rocket" colour="0xFFFF20" duration="1000">
    <Position x="500" y="-384"/>
    <Velocity x="-3" y="10"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="12000" type="Rocket" colour="0xFF2020" duration="1000">
    <Position x="0" y="-384"/>
    <Velocity x="0" y="10"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="13000" type="Rocket" colour="0xFF20FF" duration="1000">
    <Position x="-500" y="-384"/>
    <Velocity x="3" y="10"/>
  </Firework>


  <Firework begin="4000" type="Fountain" colour="0xffFF40" duration="5000">
    <Position x="0" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="5000" type="Fountain" colour="0x4020FF" duration="4000">
    <Position x="-200" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="6000" type="Fountain" colour="0xff5099" duration="3000">
    <Position x="200" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>

  <Firework begin="7000" type="Fountain" colour="0x20FF40" duration="5000">
    <Position x="0" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="8000" type="Fountain" colour="0x4020FF" duration="4000">
    <Position x="400" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="9000" type="Fountain" colour="0xff5099" duration="3000">
    <Position x="-400" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>


  <Firework begin="10000" type="Fountain" colour="0xff8040" duration="1000">
    <Position x="-450" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="10500" type="Fountain" colour="0x40ffFF" duration="1000">
    <Position x="-220" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="11000" type="Fountain" colour="0xffff99" duration="1000">
    <Position x="0" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="11500" type="Fountain" colour="0xff00ff" duration="1000">
    <Position x="220" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>
  <Firework begin="12000" type="Fountain" colour="0x40ffFF" duration="1000">
    <Position x="450" y="-384"/>
  </Firework>

</FireworkDisplay>
```

Comment: This question tickles me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (attr == "Fountain")
```

This is wrong. It compares pointers, not the string content. Use strcmp. Check each occurrence.

```
if ( rocket = true)
```

This will always be true, because it is an assignment, use == instead. Check each occurrence.

Comment: ooo ye thanks, but what do you mean by check each occurence ?

Comment: I mean the same kind of expression appears more times in the code, correct them all.

Comment: ok i understand now i did do that naturally thanks for your response. i came up with this code to extract the data out of the xml to my variable do you see anything wrong with it before i change everything else?

    timeUntillLaunch = elem->FirstChildElement("begin")-       >QueryFloatAttribute(attr,&timeUntillLaunch);

Comment: The return value of QueryFloatAttribute is a status value, whether the query was successful etc. So assigning that to the time variable is not a good idea, it would overwrite the queried float value.

Comment: int QueryAttributeStatus = elem->FirstChildElement("begin")- >QueryFloatAttribute(attr,&timeUntillLaunch);
if (QueryAttributeStatus != TIXML_SUCCESS) /* handle error */

Comment: thanks i tried what you told me but im getting this error when running  the program Unhandled exception at 0x77538dc9 in Fireworks.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.

Comment: The code presumably would like to write a member of an object at offset 0x14, but the address of the object is null. Decompose your complex expressions, add assertions, debug.

Comment: thanks for all the help you have given, i have updated my code but still cant get the attributes from the xml have you got experience using any xml parsing and can show me where im going wrong?